# Nodejs SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when adding function keyword

Tags: javascript

I am new to nodejs and JavaScript. I am writing automation framework using pageobject model using webdriver.io v5. I am facing two issues and would appreciate some clarification.

```
****************** Question 1 ******************
I have the following format code which works fine but returns Undefined as return value in main class

class ABC.js
***************
class ABC {
   constructor() {};
   extractCode() {
     return (1 > 2).valueOf();// I am expecting false as output
   }
}
module.exports = ABC;
*********** class D.js *******

var ABC = require('ABC');
class D extends ABC {
   const abc = new ABC();
   console.log(abc.extractCode());// I get undefined
}
************** Question 2 ************
    class ABC.js
    ***************
    class ABC {
       constructor() {};
       function extractCode() {
         return (1 > 2).valueOf();// I am expecting false as output
       }
    }
    module.exports = ABC;
```

I get the following error :

```
function extractCode() {
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Why is adding function keyword throwing error on JavaScript?

Comment: You're not closing the Function

Comment: @tramada Updated the code. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

> `return (1 > 2).valueOf();// I am expecting false as output`

Just `return 1 > 2;`. The expression already evaluates to a boolean value. No need for `valueOf()`.

---

**Question 2:**

You're [declaring a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) on a class. So this is valid:

```js
class A {
  extractCode () {
   // do stuff
  }
}
```

But what you're doing in your code is trying to declare a freestanding function in the context of a class definition, which isn't valid js.

---

**Observation**

Why are you instantiating ABC inside a class that extends ABC?

```js
class D extends ABC {
   const abc = new ABC(); // why?
   console.log(abc.extractCode());// I get undefined
}
```

```js
class ABC {
  extractCode () {
    return 1 > 2;
  }
}

class DEF extends ABC {} // inherits extractCode from ABC

class GHI extends DEF {
  extractCode () { // override to change the subclass behavior
    return 'bananas';
  }
}

const abc = new ABC();
console.log(abc.extractCode()); // false

const def = new DEF();
console.log(def.extractCode()); // false

const ghi = new GHI();
console.log(ghi.extractCode()); // bananas
```

These questions are more about fundamental javascript syntax than all the technologies you tagged it with. This has nothing at all to do with jquery, node.js, reactjs, or angular-fullstack.

Read up on the basics of javascript.

Comment: I tried that return 1 >2 and I get Undefined on main class

Comment: I am still learning class patters in JS. I am from Java background. But to answer your question on why I am using class declaration, I need to use the methods from ABC into class D which should give me value false. I have declared require('ABC') before the class definition of D and instantiated ABC inside class D. I know this might be wrong, still trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

For question 2: It should just be `extractCode(){}`, remove the `function` keyword. This is because you don't need it when declaring class methods. Also add a closing bracket.

Try this:

```
    class ABC {
       constructor() {};
       extractCode() {
         return (1 > 2).valueOf();
       }
    }
    module.exports = ABC;
```